# Generate states for depth first search

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

So while practicing on USACO, I got stuck on this question.

Question Description : There are N lamps in the room (all are initially switched on). There are 4 switches for the lamps with each switch toggles specific lamps like:

```
Switch 1 : Toggles all the lamps
Switch 2 : Toggles all ordered numbered lamps
Switch 3 : Toggles all even numbered lamps
Switch 4 : Toggles all numbers that have modulus 1 with 3 (1, 4, 9)
```

A number c is supplied which represents the total number of switch presses.
Initially all lamps are on. States of some of the lamps in the final states are also supplied.

The job is to list all the possible final states that the bulbs can be.

So for this I came up with the a solution based on Depth First Search. I represent each bulb by an element in array and bulb i is on if if array[i-1] is 1, off if array[i-1] = 0. Here is my code

```
/**
* Created by hp on 21-05-2015.
*/
import java.util.*;
public class lamps {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numLamps = myScanner.nextInt();
    int[] startState = new int[numLamps];
    for(int i = 0; i < numLamps; i++){
        startState[i] = 1;
    }
    int numSwitchPressed = myScanner.nextInt();
    int[] finalState = new int[numLamps];
    /*
        -1 represents the lamp's state in the final state,
        whose state is not stated , can be both on and off
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < numLamps; i++){
        finalState[i] = -1;
    }

    /*
        ON Lamps in the final state
     */
    int on = myScanner.nextInt();
    while(on != -1){
        finalState[on-1] = 1;
        on = myScanner.nextInt();
    }

    /*
        OFF Lamps in the final state
     */
    int off = myScanner.nextInt();
    while(off != -1){
        finalState[off-1] = 0;
        off = myScanner.nextInt();
    }

    //TESTING THE GENERATE STATES METHOD HERE
    ArrayList<int[]> nextStates = nextStates(startState);
    for(int[] x: nextStates){
        for(int y: x){
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.println("========================================");
    callSearch(finalState, numSwitchPressed);
}
/*
    Generate the states that are results of pressing each switch
    Switch 1 : Toggle all
    Switch 2 : Toggle odd numbered lamps(effectively indices 0,2,4,6, )
    Switch 3 : Toggle even numbered lamps(effectively indices 1, 3, 5, 7)
    Switch 4 : Toggle lamps numbered 3x+1 (1, 4, 7, 10, 13)
 */
public static ArrayList<int[]> nextStates(int[] presentState){
    int len = presentState.length;
    ArrayList<int[]> nextState = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] switchOne = new int[len];
    int[] switchTwo = new int[len];
    int[] switchThree = new int[len];
    int[] switchFour = new int[len];

    // Switch One : Toggle All
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        switchOne[i] = 1 - presentState[i];
    }
    nextState.add(switchOne);

    //Switch Two : Toggle odd numbered lamps
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            switchTwo[i] = 1 - presentState[i];
        }
        else{
            switchTwo[i] = presentState[i];
        }
    }
    nextState.add(switchTwo);

    // Switch Three : Toggle even numbered lamps
    // 1, 3, 5, 7 , 9
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(i % 2 != 0){
            switchThree[i] = 1 - presentState[i];
        }
        else{
            switchThree[i] = presentState[i];
        }
    }
    nextState.add(switchThree);

    // Switch four : Toggle 1, 4, 7, 10
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(i % 3 == 1){
            switchFour[i] = 1 - presentState[i];
        }
        else{
            switchFour[i] = presentState[i];
        }
    }
    nextState.add(switchFour);
    return nextState;
}
/*
    def searchFinal (cntSoFar, FixedCnt, currentState, FinalState):
        if cntSoFar == FixedCnt:
            if currentState == FinalState:
                print currentState
                return
            return
        ListOfNextStates = generatenextState(currentState)
        for each new_state in ListOfNextStates:
            searchFinal(cntSoFar+1, FixedCnt, new_state, FinalState)
 */
public static void searchFinal(int cntSoFar, int FixedCnt, int[] currentState, int[] finalState){
    if(cntSoFar == FixedCnt){
        if(same(currentState, finalState)){
            for(int i = 0; i < finalState.length; i++){
                System.out.print(currentState[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<int[]> nextStates = nextStates(currentState);
    for(int[] states: nextStates){
        searchFinal(cntSoFar+1, FixedCnt, states, finalState);
    }
}
/*
    WRAPPER METHOD FOR searchFinal
 */
public static void callSearch(int[] finalState, int FixedCnt){
    int len = finalState.length;
    int[] start = new int[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        start[i] = 1;
    ArrayList<int[]> firstCandidates = nextStates(start);
    for(int[] state: firstCandidates){
        searchFinal(0, FixedCnt, state, finalState);
    }
}
public static boolean same(int[] currentState, int[] finalState){
    int len = finalState.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(finalState[i] != -1){
            if(currentState[i] != finalState[i])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

As you can see I am generating the next states in the nextState method. Checking that the final state requirements are met in the same method.

My question (sorry for the long context): If the initial state of lamp is 1111111111(say 10 lamps, all are on ) and c is 1 (number of switch presses allowed), then there are only four states to search for, namely:

1. 0000000000 (Switch 1 pressed)
2. 0101010101 (Switch 2 pressed)
3. 1010101010 (Switch 3 pressed)
4. 0111011101 (Switch 4 pressed)

The final state condition is that lamp 7 should be off. (We don't care about any other lamps)
So the answer should be

```
0000000000 (All are off)
0101010101 (1,3,5,7,9 are off)
```

But the grader shows the answer as

```
0000000000
0101010101
0110110110
```

QUESTION: The third state of the grader answer, where did this come from? I mean since c is 1 (allowed number of switch pressed) the only possible states of the lamps are the 4 listed earlier. How is the 3rd state of lamps mentioned in grader answer possible?

Comment: Problem statement link, please.

Comment: Define `ordered numbered`!

Comment: If lamp numbers start at 1, pressing the 4th switch will produce the last result. also pressing the 4.th switch would certainly not produce result `0111011101`, even if you start lamp numbers at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Switch 4 : Toggles all numbers that have modulus 1 with 3

```
1 % 3 = 1
4 % 3 = 1
7 % 3 = 1
10 % 3 = 1
```

Switch #1: `0000000000` <-

Switch #2: `0101010101` <-

Switch #3: `1010101010`

Switch #4: `0110110110` <-

Comment: Oh yea, you are right . I think I will have to change my entire program a bit since there are other mistakes (like not checking if a generated stated was visited earlier ).

Answer (score 1):

```
7 % 3 = 1
```

you probably have missed this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution idea is on the right track, but your code is a kind of a nightmare :(

Think of the state of the lamps as an N bit vector. For N=4, 0000 represents all off and 1111 represents all on.

If you divide the N bit vector into sets of 6 bits (excluding any trailing bits of course), every set will have the exact same value regardless of which switches you perform. That is, if N >= 12, bits 0 through 5 will look exactly like bits 6 through 11. Thus, you can represent each switch operation as a bit-wise operations applied to a 6-bit vector.

DFS is the right place to start, but your current DFS tree has 4^c nodes. Take advantage of cycle detection and the limited size of a 6-bit vector to avoid repetitive computation.